# How to access value of map with a key if key was not found in scala?

Tags: scala

Assume I have

```
var mp = Map[String,String]()

.....

val n = mp("kk")
```

The above will throw runtime error in case key "kk" did not exist.

I expected n will be null in case key did not exist. I want n to be null if key did not exist.

What is the proper way to handle this situation in scala with a short code sample?

Comment: Never use `null` in scala. Null values are "replaced" by Options.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't really want null, as that's almost always a sign of bad coding in Scala.  What you want is for n to be of type Option[String], which says that the value is either a String or is missing.   The right way to do that is with the .get() method on you map

```
val n = mp.get("kk")
```

If you really do need null (for interop with Java libraries, for example), you can use .getOrElse()

```
val n = mp.getOrElse("kk", null)
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
val valueOpt = mp.get("kk")
```

Your result is of type `Option[String]` and can be either `None` or `Some(actualValue)`. You can use pattern matching to find out:

```
valueOpt match {
  case Some(value) => println(value)
  case None => println("default")
}
```

A more appropriate way to do that kind of things, however, is to use the methods on `Option`, e.g.:

```
println(valueOpt.getOrElse("default"))
```

Look for the API docs for `Option` [there](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option).

**Edit:** Note that `Map`itself directly defines a `getOrElse` method, too, as shown in Dave's answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
val conversionRatios:mutable.Map[String, Double] = mutable.Map[String, Double](
    "USD" -> 2.0,
    "CNY" -> 3.0
  )

val currentRate = conversionRatios.apply(key) // it will return you value or NoSuchElementException will be thrown
```